# Find the set of letters corresponding to a set of words

Tags: logical-deduction, word, knowledge, lateral-thinking

Each word in the following list corresponds to one letter:

rôle résumé Jalapeño xoriço ö führer

The combination of letters can be represented as ----uu

Here, the -'s represent the missing letters. The last two letters are u's.

**Hint 1 :**

> The meaning or language of the words has nothing to do with the letters

**Hint 2 :**

> Only some letters in the words are useful. The combination of letters wouldn't change if the other non-important words are replaced/deleted.

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be a **seven** letter word? One is repeated but not another.

Comment: No, Each word corresponds to one letter, even though they are repeated. ö and führer both correspond to the same letter - u.

Comment: They correspomnd to the modifiers. The umlaut is used twice, why not the acute?

Comment: Oh, the logic was supposed to be that - The letter corresponding to the word must be the first letter of the name of the accent used in the word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer is

> catcuu

Explanation:

> first letters of accent symbols, i.e.: **c**ircumflex, **a**ccent/ **a**cute (from @WeatherVane), **t**ilde, **c**edilla, **u**mlaut, **u**mlaut

Comment: rot13: Gur **npprag** pbhyq or **nphgr** ohg fgvyy gur fnzr nafjre.

Answer (score 1):

Half hearted guess:

> (Considering the answer **----uu** is probably not a proper word in any language)
>
>  The six words are in the languages
>
>  French (Français)
>  French (Français)
>  Spanish (Español)
>  French (Français)
>  German (Deutsch)
>  German (Deutsch)
>
>  Given that the last 2 words both represent a **u** my guess is that the letter to be used is the Nth letter in the language name (in its own language) in the order used.
>
>  1 ***F***rançais
>  2 E***s***pañol
>  3 De***u***tsch
>
>  Making the answer
>
>  **FFsFuu**
>
>  but I have no idea what that means.

Comment: Not a bad attempt. You have found a correlation ,but it's not the one I had in mind. I shall add some hint to the question.

Comment: From the added hints, *V nz grzcgrq gb guvax gung gur fvk nppragrq be zbqvsvrq yrggref ner hfrq, ohg gung qbrf abg rkcynva jul gur h nccrnef gjvpr*.

Comment: Uhm, what do you mean?

Comment: *Gur fvk nppragrq yrggref ner "brapbh"*.

Comment: English please.

Comment: It was in "rot13".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93506/discussion-between-nolandsman-and-weather-vane).

Comment: @WeatherVane Please consider using this format for [rot13 comments](//puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6577):  rot13(Uv zbz!). One of our regulars [wrote a userscript](//stackapps.com/q/7927) to decode rot13 text on hover, and using that format for such text is a welcome convenience for those of us with that userscript.

Comment: @Rubio thank you for the advice.